# Exporting html to Excel / CSV using tableExport, the exported file loses its formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

i am to trying export a report data / html to excel / csv using tableExport with this code logic

```
$('#tblRpt').tableExport({ type: 'csv', escape: 'false', tableName: 
'yourTableName' });
```

this code works in other reports which has simple html structure. The report which i am trying to export has **nested tables** in it. The exported file loses its html formatting. I don't have choice to use third party plugin because of project optimization issues.

**Please suggest me a way to solve this issue without using any third party tool/plugin, Thank you**

**This is the html of my report which i am trying to export.**

```
        <tbody><tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="no-border-right"><strong></strong></td>
        <td align="right" valign="top" class="no-border-left">10/01/2020 
     &nbsp; 10:53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" class="no-border-right"><strong>User: Practical Head 
    Office</strong></td>
        <td width="60%" align="center" class="no-border-left no-border-right">
            <strong id="MidRptHeading">
                M.I.D Report -                     Curent Fleet Only
            </strong> (01 Dec 2019 - 31 Dec 2019) 
        </td>
        <td width="20%" align="right" valign="top" class="no-border-left"> 
  <strong></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0; border:0;">
            <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th valign="top"><strong>Reg no</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top"><strong>Insure type</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top"><strong>Make</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top"><strong>Model type</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top"><strong>Derivative</strong></th>
                        <th align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Engine size</strong></th>
                        <th align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Date of Registration</strong></th>
                        <th align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Value</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Seats</strong></th>
                        <th align="right" valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Gross vcl wt</strong></th>
                        <th align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Vehicle on date</strong></th>
                        <th align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Vehicle off date</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top"><strong>Location</strong></th>
                        <th valign="top" style="text-align: center;"><strong>VIN number</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tblMidVehiclesList">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">KP69WBZ</td>
                            <td valign="top">Car</td>
                            <td valign="top">NISSAN</td>
                            <td valign="top">QASHQAI</td>
                            <td valign="top">QASHQAI DIG-T TEKNA</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">1332</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">20/09/2019</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top"></td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">4</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">05/12/2019</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">CHIPPENHAM</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">SJNFFAJ11U2647316</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">BJ69JXU</td>
                            <td valign="top">Car</td>
                            <td valign="top">PEUGEOT</td>
                            <td valign="top">Peugeot GTL 1.2 GT LINE</td>
                            <td valign="top">308 GT LINE PURETECH S/S</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">1200</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">27/09/2019</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top"></td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">4</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">10/12/2019</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">CHIPPENHAM</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">VF3LPHNSJKS346785</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">KN69TGX</td>
                            <td valign="top">Van up to 3.5T</td>
                            <td valign="top">VOLKSWAGEN</td>
                            <td valign="top">Transporter T30</td>
                            <td valign="top">TRANSPORTER T30 H-LINE TD</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">1968</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">30/09/2019</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top"></td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">2</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">3000</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">12/12/2019</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">CHIPPENHAM</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">WV1ZZZ7HZKH180620</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; padding: 0;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0; border:0; vertical-align:top;">
            <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="40%" style="padding: 0; border:0; vertical-align:top;">
                        <table width="100%" class="table-summary">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td width="17%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="14%" align="center" valign="top"><strong>At Start of Month</strong></td>
                                <td width="8%" align="center" valign="top"><strong>Current</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><strong>Owned vehicles</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">21</td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><strong>Leased vehicles</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">38</td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">3</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><strong>Temporary vehicles</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><strong>Total fleet</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top"><strong>59</strong></td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top"><strong>3</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%" style="padding: 0; border:0; vertical-align:top;">
                        <table width="100%" class="table-summary">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="center" valign="top"><strong>Current fleet</strong></td>
                                <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>Car</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">2</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>Minibus</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>Motorhome up to 3.5T</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>Motorhome 3.5T-7.5T</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>MPV</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>Van up to 3.5T</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">1</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>Van 3.5T-7.5T</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top"> <strong>HP Cars</strong></td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
                                        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%" style="padding: 0; border:0; vertical-align:top;"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" valign="top" align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid #000;"><strong>End of report</strong></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: So what is your expected output? What should be the structure of your exported file?

Comment: i want the same formatting in exported file which this code is showing in browser on front end.

Comment: In which file format?

Comment: @MayankPatel: in csv or xlsx format